# Flutter WebSocket Not connection Unsupported operation:platform_version Error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/status.dart' as status;



void socketconnect() {
try {
  channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://52.31.149.80:1883');
  channel.stream.listen((message) {
    channel.sink.add('received!');
    channel.sink.close(status.goingAway);
  });
} catch (event) {
  print(event);
}
```

> My websocket information is as above. When I run an application, I get the error unsupported operation: Platform._version. How can I fix.
>
> web_socket_channel: ^2.1.0
>
> I tried all versions and the problem still persists. !!!!!!!!!

Comment: try with any `web_socket_channel: `

Comment: Are you telling me to change the version?

Comment: yes you just try with out version `web_socket_channel: `

Comment: ok I will try. thank u

Comment: I tried all versions and the problem still persists.